# javascript library from gwt's java

Tags: gwt

How can I add a JavaScript library to a GWT project and call its functions from the java code?
I want to use [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the library's function calls in GWT using [JS Overlay Types](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay). Then use the resulting Java calls conveniently and with full IDE support.